# How can I change this function to random on click? currently sticks on same color class out of 4 options

Tags: javascript, arrays, colors

Struggling to have the script work 'on click' by selecting one of the 4 random colour classes.

Currently selects one at random, but does not refresh on individual clicks of `#myNav`.

I have tried using `toggleClass` also, however I believe it is down to poor coding as I am very new to js.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var colors = ['black','blue','mistyrose','white'];
var new_color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
$('#myNav').addClass(new_color);
});
```

Comment: please add more html & js code

Comment: You need to add a click [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) for `#myNav`

Comment: Placing the code inside of `$('#myNav').on('click', function (e) {...});` instead of `document.ready` might help.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
myNav.classList.toggle(new_color);
```

```js
function changeColor() {
  var colors = ['black', 'blue', 'mistyrose', 'white'];
  var new_color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  myNav.classList.toggle(new_color);
}
```

```css
.box { width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid black; cursor: pointer; }

.black { background: black; }
.blue { background: blue; }
.mistyrose { background: mistyrose; }
.white { background: white; }
```

```html
<div id="myNav" class="box" onclick="changeColor()"></div>
```

Comment: I need it to toggle existing classes that are the colour themes.

So on opening it can show a choice of 4 different classes which are the colours, but currently when closing the chosen colour class is still present and does not disappear. I need it so the other random colours work also.

Comment: @Shawdog I update answer - if it helps, dont forget to click on big gray check button on its left to accept it

Answer (score 0):

may be this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var colors = ['black','blue','mistyrose','white'];

  function getRandomColor() {
    return colors[ Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length) ];
  }

  $('.button').click(function() {
    var color = getRandomColor();
    $('#myNav').addClass(color);
  });
});
```